# CGContextRef with two frame

Tags: iphone, ipad, quartz-graphics, cgcontext

I have two frames with point and lines on them that i would like to do a fill with. Does CGContextRef work will with filling if the two point of lines are on different frames?

I am figuring if they contain the same CGContextRef it wouldn't matter would it?

Heres the idea:

```
    if(dp.gPoints == nil || dp.gPoints->size() < 1)
    return;
CGContextRef UserGraphBuff = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextBeginPath(UserGraphBuff);
vector<CGPoint>::iterator k = dp.gPoints->begin();
CGContextMoveToPoint(UserGraphBuff, (*k).x, (*k).y);
++k;
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UserGraphBuff, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
while(k != dp.gPoints->end()){
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UserGraphBuff, (*k).x, (*k).y);
    ++k;
}
vector<CGPoint>::iterator L = dp.dPoints->end();
while(L != dp.dPoints->begin()){
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UserGraphBuff, (*L).x, (*L).y);
    --L;
}
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UserGraphBuff, (*k).x, (*k).y);
CGContextSetFillColor(UserGraphBuff, CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]));
CGContextClosePath(UserGraphBuff);
CGContextEOFillPath(UserGraphBuff);
```

Maybe there is an issue with my code, which explains why this isn't working.
Any information would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's your problem, bit your second loop is wrong. It dereferences `dp.dPoints->end()` and skips `dp.dPoints->begin()`. It needs to be this:

```
while (L != do.dPoints->begin()) {
    --L;
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UserGraphBuff, (*L).x, (*L).y);
}
```

Comment: i found out the issue shortly before you posted this. It has to do with how drawRect is used.